# How to automate git commits in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, git, bitbucket, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime txt editor for my coding and source tree for all my dev projects and I regularly commit my changes at the end of the day and push them to remote repository, sometimes even more often but I try to do the at the end of every work day.

Sometimes it happens to me that I forgot to commit and push.

Is it possible to do this somehow automatically at the times and periods I set?

Comment: What about useful commit messages? How would that work? You are using useful commit messages right?

Comment: start here:  [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html)

Comment: yes, I'm using usefull messages, but I would like to have a fallback if I forget to commit and push :)

Answer (score 6):

Don't do this.

Version control is not a backup system.  If you want a backup system, use one.  There's a number of free, automatic, online backup services to choose from.  A simple trick is to put your project files in a Dropbox folder or the like.

Commits in git are about creating a record of why changes were made.  It has to be useful to someone else trying to understand your code in the future (who might be you in six months).  At it's most basic level it must answer the question "why is this code written this way?"  Commits should be done when you've finished a single logical change.  Fixed a bug, added a feature, changed a name, and so on.  This splits up the changes into easy to review chunks, and it makes it easy to describe what you've done.  If the commits are just whatever you did today, that's help to no one.  If you log everything you've done for the day, the commits will be too big, contain multiple changes, and it will be difficult to figure out what code goes with what change.

Commits are also very useful as checkpoints for the last time the code worked.  If you only commit when all tests pass, then debugging is much easier.  What broke the code?  Something in `git diff`.  If you just commit at the end of the day, you're likely to commit broken code.  Then you lose this very powerful debugging technique.

Git has an even more powerful debugging tool called [bisect](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git).  It can automatically find the commit which caused a bug.  It relies on the idea that each commit is working code.

Habitually pushing at the end of the day is even worse.  If your code isn't ready to be shared with others, don't push it.

Unlike Subversion, Git deliberately separates the concept of commit and push.  Pushing is sharing your work on others.  It is very important to avoid pushing broken code, even in a branch.  Other people on the project (including those in the future) should have a reasonable expectation that code they pull works.  Then they know any failure is the fault of the merge.  If you always have to question whether the code in the shared repository works, it slows work down immensely.  If you push broken code, pushing is *inflicting* your work on others.

You might say "I'm working alone".  This is a very bad habit to get into.  You won't always be working alone.  Or if you work like this, maybe you will!  There will come a time months or years from now when you will look at your code and you won't remember why you wrote it that way.

There is a small exception to this rule.  Continuous integration services (such as [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/)) require you to push code to test it.  That said, you still commit logical changes and you still run the local tests.

Comment: nicely explained, and I believe I will stick to your logic and comment more on commits and as you say one day me or someone else will rely on this comments! Thanks for taking the time to write this!